# calc function leaving extra space in container despite children adding up to 100% minus the gutter

Tags: css, sass

There are 2 children within a container that should take up equal amount of space, minus the horizontal gutter (6rem).

I've tried using these calculations to determine the children's size:

- calc(50% - 3rem)
- calc((100% - 6rem) / 2)

However, both leave extra space as you can see [the bellow picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Ama.png) (the container is grey and the children are red).

[image]
SCSS Code:

```
.row {
  max-width: 114rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  .col-1-of-2 {
    width: calc(50% - 3rem);
    background-color: orangered;
    float: left;
    &:not(last-child) {
      margin-right: 6rem;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/*Generated CSS from SCSS*/

.row {
  max-width: 114rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row .col-1-of-2 {
  width: calc(50% - 3rem);
  background-color: orangered;
  float: left;
}

.row .col-1-of-2:not(last-child) {
  margin-right: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1-of-2">Col 1 of 2</div>
  <div class="col-1-of-2">Col 1 of 2</div>
</div>
```

My question is: how can I have both children take up 50% of the container minus the gutter?

Comment: typo issue --> `:last-child` (with `:`)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using floats for positioning unless really needed, they are unreliable.
I am assuming you are not using bootstrap.
Set your `.row` to `display: flex` and give it `justify-content: space-around`.
Then set your `.col-1-of-2` to `width: calc(50% - 3rem)`.
This way you will have 1.5rem on the left, same on the right and 3rem on the middle.
No need to do anything else messing with margins and paddings.

Remember that percentage widths are based on the container `width`, not on its `max-width`, so you need to specify that even if it's another percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it like this:

```
.row .col-1-of-2:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 6rem;
}
```